# work and energy dilemma in an inclined

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, conservation-laws, work

An example problem done in my book:

> A driver was driving a car of mass 1000 kg through an inclined plane which makes an angle of 30° with plane with a velocity of 25 m/s . Then he saw a boy 50 m ahead and stopped ( travelled 50m and then stopped). Now, describe how the energy is conserved [given that friction is 11150 N].

Using simple trigonometry we can find that $sin ~30° = \frac h {50}$ [ here $h$ represents perpendicular distance between ground and car] so $h = 25 ~\rm m$

Total mechanical energy was : 
$$mgh + \frac 1 2 m v^2 = (1000 \cdot 9.8 \cdot 25) + (0.5 \cdot 1000 \cdot 25^2)$$
 which equals to $557500 ~\rm J$. Now when the car stopped it's potential and kinetic energy is 0.

The energy needed to stop the car is 
$$F_f \cdot \Delta x = 11150 \cdot 50 = 557500 ~\rm J$$ 
(where $F_f$ is the force of friction, and $\Delta x$ is the displacement), thus the car maintained the conservation theorem...

My question is: why is friction treated as resultant force acting on the car?            Friction should be the resistance force and the resultant force acting on car would be: 
$$F_f - m g sin ~30° = 11150 - 1000*9.8*sin ~30°$$ 
which is $6250 ~\rm N$ and so energy needed to stop the car is $(6250 ~\rm N \cdot 50 ~\rm m) = 312500 ~\rm J$, so according to my approach its not equal to $557500 ~\rm J$

... Where am I getting these concepts wrong?

Comment: Please see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) help post to learn how to write your equations in a *way* nicer way i.e. in $\LaTeX$, in order to improve legibility. Thanks!

Comment: @tahsin: In my opinion, this is a fairly specific question about a fairly specific homework problem. I suggest that you edit the question so that it about a [general concept](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and not just this specific problem. Also I would like to ask you to improve the formatting of your question (you don't have to use LATEX - breaking it up into paragraphs would already help).

Comment: This question boils down to: "Why do I use friction force * distance rather than net force * distance when conserving energy?"

Comment: Formatted the math, and cleaned up the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

### General Question:

Why should I use just the friction force rather than the net force to integrate over distance when conserving energy?

### Answer:

In energy conservation problems each way of storing energy generally gets it's own term. In the example problem there is a gravitational potential energy term (GPE), a kinetic energy (KE) term, and a friction term. The friction term should equal the amount of energy dissipated as heat, which is always the friction force times distance<sup>1</sup> regardless of what other forces are acting on the body.

If you do go ahead and use net force anyway, then that resulting energy term would include all  energy contributions except kinetic. This may actually be useful in some scenarios.

Note that indeed the 312500 J calculated with net force * distance does indeed equate with the difference in kinetic energy.

<sup>1</sup>Strictly speaking it should be $\int F \cdot \vec t \,dl$ the integral of the dot product of the force with the tangent vector of the path, but in cases where the force is constant and parallel to the path, the result is the same a multiplication of the force by the distance.

Comment: Thanks for your response......you want to tell that when im dealing with net force im only calculating the kinetic energy conservation, right? If i truly take all the forces accounted in net force then i should also calculate the change in potential energy like how much potential energy is conserved when the car also covered a distance of 25 meter perpendicularly....correct me if im wrong

Comment: When you calculate the work done by the net force, it will always equal the change in kinetic energy. This is because the net force is caused by gravity and friction so the work associated with the sum of those forces is equal to the sum of energy converted to heat by friction, and the GPE change. The work done by the force of gravity is exactly equal to the change in potential energy: $m\,g\,\sin(\theta) \; \Delta X = m\,g\,h$

Comment: I knew that friction only worked against kinetic energy.... What i have learnt from here can i say that friction also worked against GPE thats why we can directly use friction rather than net force to calculate the energy needed to stop the car.. Right? Thanks a lot in advance @rick

Comment: @tahsin I'm not sure what you mean by "worked against". Friction is a force. Any force multiplied by a distance will do work (transfer energy). The work done by friction on the car in your problem is -557500J. The work done by gravity on the car is 245000J. The net work done by the net force on the car is the sum of the two -312500J. This corresponds to the change in kinetic energy of the car.

Comment: I was trying to understand that if net work done on the car equalled to 312500J then 312500J enrgy transferred into some other energy from kinetic energy and 245000J energy transferred into some other energy from GPE....? Im not fluent in English, pardon me @rick

Comment: "Worked against" term was used to say that work done by friction covered not only change in kinetic energy but also the change in GPE... Thanks for asking @rick